# What is the best practice to upload a large video file in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, video, inputstream, okhttp

Currently I'm using Kotlin and OkHttp on my Android App, and I'm using an api to manage videos, to do so I need to upload them with http requests.

With this api there is two way to post videos :

- file size is less than 128mb
- or file is bigger than 128

for the first one there is no issue with it, I just have to do a simple post request with the file and it works well.
But the second is more difficult, I have to upload the video by chunks.
In the request header I have to specified the Content range for each chunk.

Something like this :

Content-Range: bytes 0-999999/4582884

Content-Range: bytes 1000000-1999999/4582884

and so on...

The solution could be to split the file for each chunk but I will have an issue if the device have not enough storage space.

So to avoid that I think I can use InputStream, but I tried it with no success as you can find on this post ([Android how to post InputStream by chunks using okhttp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64557764/android-how-to-post-inputstream-by-chunks-using-okhttp))

I'm wondering if this is the best way to do it, or if the only solution is to split the file or maybe something else.

I've been stuck for a while now, and I didn't get any response on my previous post, I hope this one will have one.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225379/discussion-on-question-by-romain-petit-what-is-the-best-practice-to-upload-a-lar).